# How to construct a line perpendicular to a plane

Tags: geometry, 3d, geometric-construction

I'm well aware of using the cross product to construct a perpendicular to two vectors.  Given a plane, is there a way to construct a line perpendicular to it, using just a straightedge and compass?  In Book XI Euclid assumes that such a line exists, but did he ever construct it?

Comment: I don't know how you draw in 3D with a pencil.

Comment: Pick an orthogonal basis for your plane. Extend it to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ via Gram-Schmidt. The third vector you add to your collection is orthogonal to your plane.

Comment: Would a pair of compass mark a sphere in 3D space, given a centre and a radius?

Comment: @JoeShmo:  OK, *calculating* a normal is straightforward.  But then... so how do you *draw* the normal with rule, straightedge, compass, as required?

Comment: Well in that case I can only echo what other people have already said: how do you draw in 3D?

Comment: And why is that so mysterious? Take a piece of paper, put a pen on it such that it is orthogonal to any vector on that piece of paper. That’s the vectors you are after.

Answer (score 2):

I assume we are able to pass planes in 3D space, and on those planes we are able to use ruler and compass and pencil. In that case:

From an arbitrary point *not* on the given plane, pass 2 planes and let them meet the given plane on two lines.

For each of those lines:

- from the initial arbitrary point, draw the perpendicular on its respective plane.
- Then, from the point where that perpendicular lands on the line, draw another perpendicular to the line, this time on the given plane.

Mark the meeting point of the latter pair of perpendiculars on the given plane. Then connect that point to the initial arbitrary point. The line you just drew is perpendicular to our given plane.

Comment: Saeed:  I assume that by "pass planes" you mean create planes.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @lewisrobinson Yes, and you're very welcome.